# Is there a way to prevent Android from switching back to mobile data once it found and then lost WiFi connection on unrooted phones?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, mobile-data

I use mobile data a few days per month. I'm charged 1$ whenever I enable the mobile internet (with WiFi not present) and then I can use it until the next day. If I don't disable it before midnight, I get charged 1$ again. This is cheaper for me than paying every month for a certain amount of gigabytes.

The problem is: sometimes I forget to disable it, and get charged when I don't use the mobile internet. Sometimes this even happens when the phone is connected to WiFi.

I saw this post, which says apps can no longer enable / disable mobile data programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically

Also there is this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gyagapen.cleverconnectivity
But it only works on rooted phones.

I've also seen other posts that say that it's only possible to disable the mobile data on rooted phones.

Is there any way to solve my problem on an unrooted phone?
If that's impossible, is there any app that could detect that mobile data is enabled and remind me to disable it before midnight?
Or is there anything else that can help in this situation?

I have Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 pro. With MIUI 12.5 and Android 11.

Comment: You can experiment with Automate app from Llama lab. It allows detecting if mobile data is enabled or not, and based on that you can automatically create a persistent notification for yourself indicating that you need to turn that thing off. No root needed for this.